# Remove all script elements using JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove all script elements from a HTML page. But for some reason, I can only remove about half of them using the below:

```
function t(){

   var r = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {

        if(r[i].getAttribute('id') != 'a'){

            r[i].parentNode.removeChild(r[i]);

        }

    }

}
```

I have that if condition so that I don't remove the executing script.

I am essentially trying to create a *dynamic* Javascript dis-abler for my selenium tests.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Loop in reverse, the count is changing when you start removing nodes.

```
var r = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

for (var i = (r.length-1); i >= 0; i--) {

    if(r[i].getAttribute('id') != 'a'){
        r[i].parentNode.removeChild(r[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Damn, I didn't spot that. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `for (var i = r.length; i--; ) {`